# UNION 2 tables with different column number then counting the the rows and set row without count to 0

Tags: mysql, sql, union-all

I have two separate query. One will show the ids and the count of the occurrence in a table and the other query will show all the ids from another table. I want to union both query but they have different column numbers and if that's possible, i want to set the count for the id that doesn't have any occurrence to 0. Please Help. Still a noob. Thanks!

```
Expeceted Result:

column name                  column name
resource_class_id            count
     21                        4
     22                        0
     23                        6
     24                        2
     25                        1
```

what i've tried so far but doesn't work is

```
SELECT r.resource_class_id from resources as r
UNION
SELECT equipment_class_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM transaction WHERE 
academic_term = 'summer'
ORDER BY r.resource_class_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Union should have same number of columns and your 2nd query should use GROUP BY since your using count()

```
SELECT r.resource_class_id, 0 as count from resources as r
UNION
SELECT equipment_class_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM transaction WHERE 
academic_term = 'summer' group by equipment_class_id
ORDER BY r.resource_class_id
```